# Another 'can't browse but can ping'

Tags: internet-connection, ping, windows-firewall, browsing

Suddenly my ability to browse disappeared yesterday. I can still ping by ip/name, I can connect to RDP computers remotely. I also have a virtual machine on my laptop that is able to browse the web.

Firewall is off. It feels like my port 80 blocked. I did sfc check but it didn't help me at all.

This happened when I was my VPN client FrontiClient.

Comment: Found the answer to this issue but have to wait for 10 more hrs to post it here as unswer:) The issue was with the settings for the proxy in IE. Somehow they got changed yesterday.

Comment: And finally found the 'cause' of this:) (ah, took me 8hrs to figure it out) - I was using fiddler and didn't noticed that it crashed, therefore proxy settings in IE didn't revert back to default='no proxy'

Comment: please do post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending most of my night/morning trying to figure out the issue by applying different 'fixes' I found the problem:

Somehow my IE's proxy settings were on with the details below:
'http' proxy was set to 127.0.0.1 port 8888
'Secure' was set to 127.0.0.1 port 8888

And 'do not use proxy' list was set to:
<-loopback>

After disabling proxy my issue was resolved. The program responsible for this 'switch' was Fiddler. For some reason it crashed (without me noticing it) and left the settings on.